# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter

Tags: filter, hbase, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run completebulkload on hbase-1.0.0.  But it meets an error,

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter"
>
> $ hadoop jar /opt/hbase-1.0.0/lib/hbase-server-1.0.0.jar
>   completebulkload -c ../conf/hbase-site.xml temp bldg
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter

Setting HADOOP_CLASSPATH with /opt/hbase-1.0.0/lib/*.jar files doesn't help.  I check all jar files with ${HBASE_HOME}/lib/*.jar with jar command. It is strange that any file doesn't include org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter class. What is missing?  Where is the class file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I find out that org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter is included at ${HBASE_HOME}/lib/hbase-client-1.0.0.jar.

Totally, I need the following HADOOP_CLASSPATH to run completebulkload.

HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HBASE_HOME}/lib/hbase-server-1.0.0.jar:${HBASE_HOME}/lib/hbase-server-1.0.0-tests.jar:${HBASE_HOME}/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:${HBA
SE_HOME}/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:${HBASE_HOME}/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:${HBASE_HOME}/lib/hbase-client-1.0.0.jar:${HBASE_HOME}/lib/hbase-common-1.0.
0.jar:${HBASE_HOME}/lib/hbase-protocol-1.0.0.jar:${HBASE_HOME}/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:${HBASE_HOME}/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar

Comment: You might also be able to set that classpath with `HADOOP_CLASSPATH='hbase classpath'` (where `'` should be a backtick, but it conflicts with the comments markdown).  This hbase command finds all of the jars for you.